# Is it possible to have the same apps from the same amazon account on 2 different devices?

Tags: applications, amazon-appstore

My kids have an android tablet each both linked to my amazon account. When I try to put the same app on both it tells me it's not possible.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: What exactly is the message that you're getting?  I doubt that it's "Not possible".  I know I have three devices hooked up to my account, and they work...

Answer (score 1):

Did you register the devices with Amazon?  You can install amazon store purchases on multiple devices, but they must be authorized.  When you are in the app store, looking at an app, there should be a list of your devices, under the purchase button, with a notation on which devices the app will work with.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to extract the app's `.apk` file using a helper app like [AppMonster](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.android_telefonie.appmanager), which would store it on your sdcard. Following this step, copy the `.apk` to the other device, and "side-load" it there (i.e. try to "start" the `.apk` on the second device, which would install the app).

You might need to enable "unknown sources" for app installation in your settings for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I do this sort of thing all the time. In fact I wrote an app to help me out with this. I uninstall and re-install applications for testing a development all the time. I need to easily be able to make copies and move ".apk" files all the time.

Please take a look at the free app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=burrows.apps.appmanager.

Simple install the app, "backup" your application of choice and then share/send the application(.apk) to another phone.

Regards,